# Athena subquery not working - incorrect table name

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to write an athena query that uses a subquery in the where clause because I want to place a restriction on an array-type field. I don't want to do a `cross join unnest` since I don't want to flatten each row.

Example query:

```
SELECT
  foo.some_scalar_field,
  foo.some_other_scalar_field
FROM "fake_db"."table_name"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM foo.some_array_field as T(item) WHERE item = "THING")
```

When I do this, I get an error saying that "foo" isn't a valid table name. I'm a bit new to athena, however a previous SQL engine I used to use supported this kind of query. Is doing this not possible in Athena?

Edit;;

I went ahead and added an unnest:

```
SELECT
  foo.some_scalar_field,
  foo.some_other_scalar_field
FROM "fake_db"."table_name"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM UNNEST(foo.some_array_field) as T(item) WHERE item = "THING")
```

Now i get an error that the correlated subquery here is not supported. It seems like Athena doesn't support correlated subqueries?

Comment: `foo` is one of the columns in the original table.

Actually, I went ahead and added an `unnest`:
```
SELECT
  foo.some_scalar_field,
  foo.some_other_scalar_field
FROM "fake_db"."table_name"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM UNNEST(foo.some_array_field) as T(item) WHERE item = "THING")
```

Now i get an error that the correlated subquery here is not supported. It seems like Athena doesn't support correlated subqueries?

Comment: @de1337ed yes Presto/Trino has quite limited support for correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `unnest` and correlated subqueries, just use [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html). Something along this lines:

```sql
SELECT
  foo.some_scalar_field,
  foo.some_other_scalar_field
FROM "fake_db"."table_name"
WHERE any_match(foo.some_array_field, item -> item = "THING")
```